# class or interface expected shows on pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have imported a multi module maven project in to Intellij IDEA 14 every thing working fine excepet there is a little annoying message shows in maven pom.xml as in the below screenshot.

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this problem.

PS: I can build the projects and the resulted application is working fine

Comment: Have you tried the IntelliJ universal solution to these problems (File/Invalidate Caches/Restart)? :)

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt It didn't help

Comment: Just simulated the problem. It can happen when you accidentaly inject language reference. Try navigating to the underline code, hit ALT-ENTER and select Un-inject language reference if it is there.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Wow thats it. Un-inject solved the issue. Please add it as an answer I'll accecpt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have accidentaly injected Java language reference into your pom.xml. To fix it, navigate to the underlined line, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and select *Un-inject Language/Reference*.

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing I don't get that I didn't inject language reference it happend automatically don't know why.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Not sure. It maybe be some hidden IDE bug, or perhaps you really did accidentaly inject the language for instance from ALT ENTER menu at some point and don't even know about it. I've looked for similar issue in IntelliJ's issue tracker and found nothing, but who knows ... important thing is that it works :) If it happens to you again try contacting JetBrains support or report it on youtrack.jetbrains.com.